# Trouble with codecs and youtube-dl on Fedora

Tags: fedora, youtube-dl, codec

I have spent about 90 minutes today trying to download a video from youtube and extract its audio.

At first I had issues with not having `ffmpeg` installed. Apparently it is no longer possible to install via `dnf`, and I cannot get RPM to work for anything (rpm -l shows nothing, despite having enabled both free and nonfree repositories). I then installed the source files and compiled them. None of the --enable-lib switches worked, so the only audio formats I could use `youtube-dl` on were m4a and aac. Neither of them could I play since I did not have the codecs. My question is:

How can I get `ffmpeg` to work with other codecs, when it does not want to enable anything via options in configure, or is there another way to install these codecs that actually works with Fedora 25 and `youtube-dl`? 
I have looked at nearly every set of instructions for this or similar question, and they have been invariably been lacking in some way.

Comment: As you mention `youtube-dl` in the title, and not `ffmpeg`: Have you tried `youtube-dl -F` and choosing a format like `youtube-dl -f18`? Should work with standard codecs.

Comment: I tried that, and it spat out a messy error as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the rpmfusion repositories. Go to https://rpmfusion.org to get them. They also have a FAQ entry about the AV codecs you might need.

Comment: I did that, but it had no effect. I suspected it is due to the fact that I did it via gnome-software which has not ever worked on my machine. Installing RPM fusion via command line was similarly without effect; rpm -l returns nothing.

Comment: Use `dnf` from the command line to install the codecs (and youtube-dl), instead of `rpm`.

Comment: I have installed them via DNF , every version both i686 and x86_64, devel and not. This is to no effect.

Comment: Actually, now I do see more options

Comment: But even after installing the package, I still have the same problem: I can only download files as .aac or .m4a, neither of which I can play. I can't use SoundConverter either, as that makes the entire system crash.

Comment: You need to install the codecs you want to use as well. Most are part of the gstreamer-plugins packages.

Comment: I have installed those ,as well as all the ffmpeg libraries via rpm . At this point, I do not doubt that these are on my computer, but my system does not recognize them.